# Interact with JPanel behind JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have been working with Java's swing library a lot recently and I have landed upon another question.

I have a transparent JLayeredPane which sits on top of a JPanel. I need to interact with the JPanel (with a mouse listener) but since I added the JLayeredPane I cannot interact with the JPanel.

As a side note, I pack my JFrame which I would like to pack around the JPanel and not the JLayeredPane but the JLayeredPane seems to take priority now.

**Example** - Keep in mind there is actually content on the panels, this is just for example.

```
public Main()
{
    // Main JPanel
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // JLayeredPane
    add(new JLayeredPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Add Mouse Listener
    mainPanel.addMouseListener(new CustomMouseListener());
}
```

Comment: when you add the layeredpane, you remove the mainpanel. as they are both targeted at the same spot. Only one component can exist in the same spot at once. maybe you want to add the layeredpane to the mainPanel.

Comment: *"I have landed upon another question."* Don't just land on it, ask it! The remaining words contain no question, just a problem description. *"this is just for example."* 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Keep in mind there is actually content on the panels,

The MouseListener should be added to the panel added to the layered pane, not the panel containing the layered pane.